# Using Javascript innerHTML to replace an onClick link with a different onClick link results in onClick not working

Tags: javascript, html, air, onclick, innerhtml

**Scenario**

I am building an HTML based Application with a set window size. I have created a link called "More >>" that when clicked has an onClick event that calls a resizeMore() function that increases the width of the application AND at the same time runs a document.getElementById(IDHERE).innerHTML to replace the "More >>" link with a "<< Less" link that has an onClick event to a resizeLess() function that basically does the same in reverse (resizes the window back to original size and replaces "<< Less" with "More >>" again so that the process can be repeated indefinitely to shrink or expand the window).

On the first click of the "More >>" link, it resizes the window correctly, and correctly changes the innerHTML to now be a "<< Less" link with a different onClick event. However, clicking the "<< Less" link does nothing, as if it doesn't recognize an onClick event at all.

However, I know that the JS function DOES work because if I create 2 separate links that each have an onClick event to the 2 resize functions, both work as I'd expect. It only appears to be when I change from More >> to << Less with innerHTML that the onClick is not working anymore.

**HTML Code**

```
<p id="moreorless">
  <a href="#" class="needMore" onClick="javascript:resizeMore();"> More >> </a>
</p>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
function resizeMore() {
document.getElementById('moreorless').innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='needMore' onClick='javascript:resizeLess();'> << Less </a>";
}

function resizeLess() {
document.getElementById('moreorless').innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='needMore' onClick='javascript:resizeMore();'> More >> </a>";
}
```

**FIDDLE**

I have created a JSFiddle to try to give an example of my issue, but for some reason even though the same code partially works for me inside my source code, JSFiddle is not doing ANYTHING when I click on my 'More >>' link. Regardless, I have provided a JSFiddle here which has all of the code that I am trying to use. (I do not know why it doesn't do anything in the Fiddle but partially works on my site) - http://jsfiddle.net/NMV5w/

Comment: When using jsfiddle, make sure to note the type of location used for the script. Below "No-Library (pure JS)" there is a default, "onLoad", selection. Changing that to "No wrap - in `<head>`" will show the fiddle working properly. http://jsfiddle.net/NMV5w/1/ There does not seem to be an issue with your code.

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/NMV5w/2/

Comment: Explaining previous comment - you should chose "No wrap - in <head>" in Frameworks & Extensions

Comment: Wow I did not expect such quick responses. Thank you for clarifying my JSFiddle issues, I have never used it before. I am glad to know that my code works fine in the fiddle but for some reason still doesn't seem to work in my application. I may need to consider this being a problem with the way Adobe AIR is handling the code.. I am using Adobe AIR with the AIRAliases.js bridge to code an HTML app within an AIR frame. The button works to change from More to Less but won't change back from Less to More! Frustrating...

Comment: If there is an error in the javascript then it could cause the event handler to break. Are you seeing any errors in your developer console when you click on less?

Comment: as an AIR app I can't use developer console in my browser because it errors on window.nativeWindow since that is an AIR specific call. Adobe AIR has something called Introspector which is its own console and when I enable it to log the results of my functions it shows perfect results for resizeMore (when I click More) but it shows literally nothing (no errors OR results at all) when I click Less. The javascript is identical for both functions other than one does a resize of += 250 and the other is -= 250. It is entirely possible that everything is right and AIR is just at fault I guess?